# How can I offer worship to Maa Baglamukhi?

Tags: mantras, guru, shakti, dasha-mahavidya, upasana

Why am I asking this question?

I don't have a Guru! also I began my Upasana with Lord Krishna! it is now that I am guided to worship **Maa Baglamukhi**!

But again one simply doesn't worship **Dasmahavidyas** without Initiation.

Maa Baglamukhi happens to be my Kuldevi, also I had dreams about her. So are there some ways I can worship Maa Baglamukhi without Guru?

Shower some light on the same, thanks!

Comment: where are u located in India ...?

Comment: Himachal Pradesh

Comment: if u can travel to Jaipur, perhaps I can share info about Guru there who can give u maa baglamukhi deeksha.

Comment: Any way I can reach him online?

Comment: I am afraid not, it will be face to face.